# GNUPLOT incorrect date behavior

Tags: gnuplot

GNU plot is giving a strange behavior with this data, but I cannot figure our why.

here is my data example :

```
-2.696764488716512156e-02 2023-05-25
-2.514640039066843094e-02 2023-05-25
-2.539875589417509363e-02 2023-05-25
-2.443511139767776813e-02 2023-05-25
-2.258826690118204833e-02 2023-05-25
-2.176542240468394215e-02 2023-05-25
```

Now using HOURS time work, but I am trying to plot for DAYS with this configuration :

```
set terminal png size 1074,806
set output 'output.png'
set datafile sep ' '
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-d%"
set format x "%m/%d"
set autoscale y
set style data lines
set xlabel 'Days'
plot "gnudataok.dat"  using 2:1 with lines lt rgb "blue"
```

But I cannot get correct dates on the X axis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWbtN.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please show a resulting graph? What exactly is not correct with the dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your script `"%Y-%m-d%"` instead of `"%Y-%m-%d"`

Note, if your time precision is just whole days, all these datapoints will be plotted on top of each other.

The following script (with some dates changed) will give the result below...

**Script:**

```
### time data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
-2.696764488716512156e-02 2023-05-25
-2.514640039066843094e-02 2023-05-25
-2.539875589417509363e-02 2023-05-26
-2.443511139767776813e-02 2023-05-26
-2.258826690118204833e-02 2023-05-27
-2.176542240468394215e-02 2023-05-27
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%m/%d" timedate
set xlabel 'Days'

plot $Data u (timecolumn(2,myTimeFmt)):1 w lines lc rgb "blue"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: still nothing, the dates are wrong check the link I posted , Now I am using your code.

Comment: @Ken90 you accepted the answer. So it's working with my code? Is it working also with your code when correcting the little typo to `"%Y-%m-%d"`?